# Is there conjectures in deep learning theory?

Tags: machine-learning

I often read that deep learning suffers from a lack of theory, compared to classical machine learning. I mean that deep learning has shown to be a powerful tool in practice but there is no proof of this effect in theory. Which leads to my question: Is there some conjectures in deep learning theory? What should be proven mathematically to build a real deep learning theory?

Comment: It would be helpful when asking about a popularized phrase (buzzword) to offer your own definition or at least narrow the Question by providing a link to a definition you accept.  Wikipedia provides [one such treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning), but the description "deep learning" is often applied to architectures as well as "techniques" (algorithms).  Some foundation is needed to offer an informed opinion as to whether a topic "suffers from a lack of theory".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any conjecture that captures all theoretical problems raised by deep learning . Also, there is not much consensus on how to properly formalize the questions. For example Naftali Tishby's group uses an information theoretic approach , while others - like Sanjeev Arora ,looks more to the (non-convex) optimization problems and different simplified or specific architectures (random or linear networks).

A good theory of deep learning should explain two things:

1.Why they generalize so well ,although the standard learning theory indicate that they should overfit .

2.Why the optimization is practically so easy ,although the current theory say it is hard.